# Does the device token change ever on up gradation of OS?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, device, token

I have question regarding Device Token update. If we upgrade OS, for example from iOS 6 to iOS 7, the device token for the app will update or it remains same as old?

I gone through the Apple document, but I didn't find any specific answer for OS up gradation. As per my knowledge and form others answer regarding same question I have below information.

> "By requesting the device token and passing it to the provider every
>   time your application launches, you help to ensure that the provider
>   has the current token for the device. If a user restores a backup to a
>   device other than the one that the backup was created for (for
>   example, the user migrates data to a new device), he or she must
>   launch the application at least once for it to receive notifications
>   again. If the user restores backup data to a new device or reinstalls
>   the operating system, the device token changes. Moreover, never cache
>   a device token and give that to your provider; always get the token
>   from the system whenever you need it. If your application has
>   previously registered, calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
>   results in iOS passing the device token to the delegate immediately
>   without incurring additional overhead."

My intention behind the question is that, I want to use device token as Unique ID, such as UDID. As after iOS 6, getting UDID method is rejected, and there is no alternative for UDID.

I know about identifierForVendor, but it is app specific & if we remove app, it will change. I want to get one Unique ID form iPhone, that never change, but I can't find any method that apple allow to store like IMEI nubmer etc.

In summery Can any ID or number that is Unique and it will never change, and we can use it for our application that can't reject by apple?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question as I know that for upgrading the OS the device token doesn't change. But I have no reference link. 
For your second question, you can use the following method to get UUID in iOS 6 or later:

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]` instead.